# Unity Static Instance becomes Null Reference on live code update

Tags: static, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I have a GameObject with a script that has variables that a lot of different scripts call to.
For instance, one variable is a Vector2 that all other moving objects in the game use to know which way the map is moving.

This script has a static Instance of itself that it applies itself to on Start().

Everything runs great but I'm running into an issue where if I edit any of the code while the game is running, when the game loads up the new code and tries to continue, anything that calls from the Instance of the gameObject gets a NullReferenceException.

I've tried setting up Singletons in hopes that maybe that'd get around the issue but those have the same effect.

Does anyone know if there's a way to use global instances of a class? I found being able to edit the code and refresh it in a live game be extremely useful... tho not as useful as having a static Instance that contains a frequently shared variable. This seems like something people should have run up against before but for the life of me I can't seem to find anything on the web about it.

I'm using C# btw =] Thanks!

Edit: adding the code for the GameController class.

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public static GameController Instance;
    public int score;
    public GameObject debugText;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText;

    public float sfxVolume = 1;

    public Vector2 scrollSpeedBase;
    public Vector2 scrollSpeed;
    public Vector3 scrollSpeedV3;
    public float mapExitPoint;
    public float timeDelta;


    void Start () 
    {
        Instance = this;
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your description of your situation is unclear.  Please update the question to include more information, such as screenshots of your gameobject structure, code samples, and what you mean when you say "when the game loads up the new code and tries to continue.". What data did you change?  Did you pause execution and resume?  Stop execution and restart?

Comment: It's nothing complex. I just have a script set up to an otherwise Empty GameController in the Hierarchy that in StartUp() Instance = this;   As for what I've changed, it can be absolutely anything. I've tested it with adding a just a single space and saving the script. The issue only occurs if I'm changing something in the scripts and saving them while the game is being played. Anything accessing the static Instance returns a NullReferenceException.

Comment: post your code, specifically highlight the line it crashes and init/assignments of the reference in question

Comment: Post the code. Btw unity doesn't serialize static fields. I never modify script while the game is running so I don't know it precisely, but I guess you should eventually validate it on reload and update the static reference.

Comment: Added the code for the GameController class. As the game runs, the public variables are changed and accessed by other classes via the Instance. When the game loads in changes while the game is live, the Instance becomes null.

Comment: I think I understand now.  @peterept is probably right when he talks about the order of execution.  See this link for instructions on how to customize the order of execution, and make sure your GameControler has the highest priority.  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html

Comment: The script is the only thing loaded at the top of the Hierarchy and works fine prior to editing the code while the game is running. Editing the code with the game running was convenient but not something I really need so I'll just go back to not doing it =] Thanks for the help everyone, was just wondering if there was a workaround or if this was a known issue as I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a limitation of live editing.

Consider: you've edited a class. In order for that updated file to be used, the code has to be recompiled and "injected" into the running game in place of the original version. Whilst any *instances* of your component can be serialized and deserialized to give some level of continuity post-edit (i.e. fields that aren't renamed will retain their values), the static field won't be - and, further, it would make no sense for `Start` to be re-run in the middle of the game, which is where your `Instance` is set.

You could prove this to be the case by storing another static variable in your class (a simpler one - like an `int`) and seeing what happens to that when you live edit. I'd imagine it would reset to zero.

Comment: What happens is the variable stays the same in the Inspector but the Instance is unreachable and returns a NullReferenceException whenever something tries to access it. I was just curious if this was something that had a known workaround but it doesn't seem like that's the case so I'll just have to stop with the live edits. Thanks for your help =]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect what you are seeing is that the static instance setup in Start() is being called after other scripts Start() calls.

You could:

- Set your script execution order priority so it gets run first (or move the initialization to the Awake method)
- Use a singleton style setup where you have a Getter method that initializes your static variable when called.

Comment: The Instance calls work fine up until I change anything in any script and save it while the game is running. Once the game loads up the changed code, it seems like the static Instance becomes null. I tried moving the Instance = this; into the Awake method and there's no change.

Comment: @Steve You need to look at the documentation for how to change the script execution order.

Comment: Even if it were an execution order problem, the NullReference persists through multiple loops through the game meaning that the Instance is never being set after the code has been changed. I don't think script execution order is the issue.

Comment: Oh I didn't really focus on your core issue of changing code in a live running app. Unity only provides that for simple debugging and experimenting/hacking IMHO. It is a known issue with live recompile that all static instances are reset. So you will need to use point 2 above that the getter checks for null and reloads the instance.